# Is it possible to open a certain activity in IOS by clicking a link ?

Tags: ios, mobile, hyperlink

what I want to achieve is by sending a link by email and when the user clicks on the email , he should be directed to the inbox of my IOS app than home page of the IOS .

Is it possible ?

I have seen AirBnB is doing it and no idea how they are doing it .

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: I believe they are using UITextView with 'Links' field enabled. And since they are links, I would check to see if `mailto:hello@example.com` would open Mail modal window / app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using URL Schemes. Set URL Scheme for your app say demoApp.

Now when you have set this up and installed the app you can go to safari and type demoApp:// hit enter and your app will open up.

Now to open specific view/screen of your app you can pass along with above url specific string say demo://inbox. When your app opens up it will call handleOpenUrl if it was already running else will call didfinishLauncingwithOptions. There you can extract the keyword inbox and can redirect your application to Inbox screen.

Now when sending an email you need to send the above url inorder to open your app fron mail.